# Age, Ratio word problem

Tags: word-problem, ratio

A is x years old. In 4 years time his brother B will be 3 times as old as him. Find the age of B in 4 years time.

Comment: What have you tried? See also [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3018996/ratio-of-money-distributed-among-friends) ratio problem.

Comment: I have tried various approaches. But my teacher restricted me to solve it by algebra.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$x$ is A's age and let's call B's age $y$ at this point in time
*Hint* : In 4 years time A: is $x+4$ years old and B is $y+4$ years old
**Solution**

> We know that B will be 3 times older than A in 4 years, aka $3*(x+4)=y+4$
> Solving for $y$ : $y=3x+8$
> In four years time B will be $y+4$ years old or aka $3x+8+4 = 3x+12$